# How to use new languages with text_to_speech library?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Good afternoon, 
I have read about [text_to_speech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) library 
and about [Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/%20%20util/Locale.html) class.

It says that *<>*

My question is: how can I use this library with languages such as 
Basque? Is it supported by this library?

Thank you very much in advance. 
Best regards, 
inler

Answer (score 0):

Check the [official Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html). It says "The TTS engine that ships with the Android platform supports a number of languages: English, French, German, Italian and Spanish. Also, depending on which side of the Atlantic you are on, American and British accents for English are both supported."

I don't know if Basque is very similar to "regular" Spanish, but I suggest you try and find out if it works for you

Comment: Hi THelper, Thanks for your rapid answer. Basque is completly different to spanish. The vocabulary, the sintaxis and the accent are completly different. Basque doesn't share the latin origin (in fact, nobody knows the origin of this language). If we use Spanish for reading texts in basque, it sounds very bad (as if you use English for reading Spanish). I don't know if there is any way to do this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think it is possible to adjust the default android TTS engine. I think there is no other option than to search for a TTS that does support Basque or create one yourself.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide and extension to TTS engine for reading basque text? I'm really confused and lost with this task! Could someone give me orientations to begin with this? -- Thank you very much for your help! --

Comment: I haven't found any documentation on how to extend the current TTS engine in the Android API or elsewhere on the Internet, so I guess it's not possible.